# Is e a generator?

Tags: group-theory

The identity ended up being the centre of a group. I'm pretty confident that the identity is a generator of the centre but the concept is new. Thanks for your input

Comment: The identity can only generate itself. Technically yes it can generate a *sub*group, but that subgroup is trivial, so I'm not sure that really counts.

Comment: @CameronWilliams The centre of a dihedral group , n bigger than 2, n odd, yields only e. From my understanding, the centre of a group is a subgroup of the group. So e should be a subgroup of the dihedral group.

Comment: The identity element always forms a one-element subgroup. It doesn't matter whether it's also the center or not. It doesn't suddenly become a subgroup when it wasn't before.

Answer (score 0):

The identity can't be a generator, unless the group in question is trivial. All it's powers/multiples are just itself.